# Japanese input to google search not working properly

Tags: discussion

I use Debian Linux with firefox 54.0.1 and ibus-anthy to input Japanese text.
Let's say I want to search ケーキを食べる. I go to the google home page(https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl) and I try to type ケーキ. Upon typing the first character google goes into predictive search and deletes the first character leaving me with えーき as the search term.

I correct this and get as far as ケーキを. Now when I try to type た for 食べる it starts to make predictions and deletes た　from the entry box. Once it's made the predictions I can type 食べる again and all is well. If I type fast enough then I can get it to not delete the text.

I only noticed it happening this week and I'm not sure whether it always used to happen. I can't find anything on google about this phenomenon. I don't know if it's a bug with ibus, firefox or google.

So this is a desperate hope that one of you has seen the problem and/or knows how to fix it.

Comment: I can confirm this with Firefox 54 and fcitx-mozc and after some testing it didn't happen with Chromium. Most likely something with the new Firefox (together with Google changes) maybe? Some possible fixes: 1. disable Google Instant 2. use address bar for Google search instead 3. use another browser 4. report this to Mozilla/Google and wait for it to get fixed if you don't want to let go of Firefox and Google Instant

Comment: @siikamiika Thanks for the confirmation. Strangely, if I go to google.co.**jp** it doesn't do predictive search anyway.  I can live without it.

Comment: You're right! Interestingly, when I tested google.co.jp on my chromium, Google Instant was working while Firefox didn't even try to use it although it was enabled in [settings](https://www.google.co.jp/preferences?hl=ja&fg=1). This is a good sign; my guess is that Google is aware and currently working on a fix because they have disabled Instant (for Firefox users) for a site where people primarily use IME to input text.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would have never expected this but guess what...

> ## [Google has dropped Google Instant Search](http://searchengineland.com/google-dropped-google-instant-search-279674)
>
> ### Several years after Google launched Google Instant, they are killing the default search feature to bring search more inline with mobile devices
>
> Barry Schwartz on July 26, 2017 at 10:31 am
>
> After launching Google Instant — Google’s method of showing search results as you type them — several years ago, Google has **removed the feature from search** effective today.
>
> (...)
>
> Now as you type, you will only see search suggestions and then be able to click on those suggestions to see the results. **The search results will not load any result pages without clicking on a search suggestion or clicking enter**.

In other words, the problem should be gone for good unless there are enough people who demand Google to restore this feature.

I still wonder why there was a period when it was disabled for Firefox users of google.co.jp but enabled for google.com, though.